# How do I run task like `object = ClassA.GetObject()` in a separate thread using BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm trying to make this line to work with `BackgroundWorker`:

```
map = Map.LoadMap(mapname);
```

…like this:

```
bw.DoWork += (map = Map.LoadMap(mapname));
```

It causes the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'game.Map' to 'System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler'`.

I just started using `BackgroundWorker` as threading component for my game, but it doesn't look like it will be easy to convert all existing methods to work with it. Is there a simple way to make this work or is it better to switch to some other threading mechanism?

Note: from the threading base I need to be able to poll for progress percentage and not messing up my existing method calls.

Comment: IMO, it would be better to create `Thread` instances, due to your requirements (like asking for a percentage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage [anonymous delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like this:

```
bw.DoWork += (sender, args) => { map = Map.LoadMap(mapname); };
```

Answer (score 1):

Backgroundworker is good because you can use the option WorkerReportsProgress = true 
this can be used to pool for a percentage

you can report progress inside the DoWork method like this

```
bw.ReportProgress(percentage);
```

I use to associate BackgroundWorker as a wrapper for what Threads would do. So I use BackgroundWorker on GUI works, and Threads on more specialized or dirty jobs (Windows Services, etc)

you dowork method has to be written like this

```
bw.DoWork += (sender, args) => { map = Map.LoadMap(mapname); };
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the type of variable map and the return type of method Map.LoadMap - are game.Map.
In your code in line

```
bw.DoWork += (map = Map.LoadMap(mapname));
```

you are doing next: get the result from Map.LoadMap(mapname), set it to variable map and after that try to use this value as a handler for DoWork event. And the type of variable map and property bw.DoWork are different.

So you just need to change this line to:

```
bw.DoWork += (sender, eventArgs) => { map = Map.LoadMap(mapname); }
```

Which will mean that you are trying to create new Delegate "(sender, eventArgs) => ..." and use it as a handler for property bw.DoWork.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BackgroundWorker like this:

```
        var worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += delegate 
        { 
             map = Map.LoadMap(mapname); 
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Keep in mind that the program will continue execution immediatly after the RunWorkerAsync() method so if you use the map variable afterwards it will probably not be a loaded map.

To continue execution after the map has been loaded you need to subscribe to the RunWorkerCompleted also:

```
        var worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += delegate 
        { 
            map = Map.LoadMap(mapname); 
        };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate 
        { 
            MapComplete(); // contiune with stuff here
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

The += operator indicates that you are attaching an event handler (DoWork is an event).

Here is an example usage:

Create an instance of the backgroundworker(in this case it will be at the class level), call the function that attaches the events **SetupBackgroundWorker()**

```
private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

private void SetupBackgroundWorker()
{
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
    bw.ReportProgress = true;
}
```

These are sample event handlers, should give you an idea

```
private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{//Just as an example, I don't ever call the functions to trigger this event
    int ProgressPercent = e.ProgressPercentage;
    object AnyOtherDataReported = e.UserState;
}
private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   //Do something when the work has been completed
   //Note: You should always check e.Cancelled and e.Error before attempting to touch the e.Result. I did not put that protection in this example.

   object TheResultFrom_DoWork = e.Result;//This is your "map" object
}
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  //object PassedInObject=e.Argument; //This is the argument you sent to RunWorkerAsync

    //Type cast PassedInObject to your correct Type
    WhateverTypeItIs_YouDidntSay mapname=(WhateverTypeItIs_YouDidntSay)e.Argument

    //Perform your task
    object returnvalue=Map.LoadMap(mapname);//This was your varriable called "map"

    //Assign the result of your task to the return value
    e.Result=returnvalue;
}
```

Pass this function the value for **mapname** and if the backgroundworker is not busy doing a previous task, it should start the process.

```
private void ProcessTheMap_InBackground(WhateverTypeItIs_YouDidntSay mapname)
{
    if (!bw.IsBusy)
    {
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(mapname);
    }
    else
    {//You are already loading something in the background
    }
}
```